# Create a new column in the dataframe that has values of other columns for that row in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change
[image]

This datafrme to the

[image]

how should I use apply function to achive this?

Comment: What operations are you doing to the numbers? It is not clear at all in your question. They are different between the two images you posted.

Comment: Could you please include the input and the expected output, **as text**, in your question so it would be easy to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['bbox'] = df.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x], axis=1)
```

so for a df that looks like:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   a  b  c
0  1  3  1
1  2  4  1
2  3  5  1
3  4  6  1
```

you'll get:

```
In [16]: df['bbox'] = df.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x], axis=1)

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   a  b  c       bbox
0  1  3  1  [1, 3, 1]
1  2  4  1  [2, 4, 1]
2  3  5  1  [3, 5, 1]
3  4  6  1  [4, 6, 1]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per your example to achieve required result, you need to convert each row in list. Add that list to new DataFrame. Once you add new list to DataFrame apply whatever calculation(your output DataFrame values are different from input DataFrame hence expecting you have done some calculation on each cell or row) you want to apply on the same.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x':[121,216,49],'y':[204,288,449],'w':[108,127,184]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y','w'])
new_data = [[row.to_list()] for i, row in df.iterrows()]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns='bbox')
print(new_df)

            bbox
0 [121, 216, 49]
1 [204, 288,449]
2 [108, 127, 184]
```